# Different line spacing for each item at UICollectionView - swift 3

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3

I have a `collection view` written programmatically with `swift 3`. It has 1 section and 6 vertical items in it. The default minimum line spacing for each item is 10 I assume, but I want to set different line spacing for each item. For example, the space between item 0 and 1 become 50 but space between item 1 and 2 become 0. How can I do that? I searched a lot but couldn't find solution. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is directly not possible by setting some property of your collection view but you can do one trick I think,

set your `minimum line spacing` and `minimum interitem spacing` to `0` like,

```
 layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
 layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0
```

so your `collection view cell` will not have any space at any side!

now keep your cell's background color as clear color!

and add `UIView` (your content) in your cell with size(less than cell size) that shows spacing between two cell. So, you can add different size of view in every cell and it will display like different space between every cell!

Or

If you don't want to resize your inner view of cell then you can return different size for your cell from delegate method `sizeForItemAtIndexPath` for different items!

For example,

***I am writing objective c code for example***,

your `sizeforitem`,

```
 - (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

if (indexPath.item == 1 || indexPath.item == 6 || indexPath.item == 7 || indexPath.item == 9 || indexPath.item == 15) {

    return CGSizeMake(screenWidth/3 -20, screenWidth/2);
}

return CGSizeMake(screenWidth/3, screenWidth/3);
}
```

and result is

[image]

Answer (score 0):

An idea could be to consider the lines spacing as "other kind of cell", like blank cell, you see? And in the method `heightForRowAtIndexPath`, when the indexPath correspond to those blank cell, you return their custom height, otherwise you return the row height of your "real" cells.

(This imply to return those blank cell in the cellForRow, and add their number to your current numberOfRowInSection count too)